# Need to split University Course code into prefix and suffix using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to split a a university course code into prefix and suffix. e.g. CSE1011 into Prefix CSE and Suffix 1011 . Prefix may be 2 or more Alphabets and suffix may be none/ 3 or more. So far I have come up with this RegEx:

```
/([A-Z]{2,})(?:\s*)([0-9]{3,})?$/g
```

```js
var courscrCode = 'CSE1011';
var courseRegex = /([A-Z]{2,})(?:\s*)([0-9]{3,})?$/g;
var splitted = courseRegex.exec(courscrCode);
console.log(splitted);
```

Also tried This. I am getting more match

```js
var courscrCode = 'CSE1011';
var courseRegex = /([A-Z]{2,})(?:\s*)([0-9]{3,})?$/g;

if (courscrCode.match(courseRegex)) {
  var splitted = courscrCode.split(courseRegex);
  console.log(splitted.length);
  if (splitted.length > 1) {
    splitted.forEach(function(value, index) {
      if ((value != '') && (value != undefined))
        console.log(value, index);
    });
  }
} else {
  console.log('course code mangled');
}
```

I need a solution where i am going to get exactly 2 sub-string prefix and suffix. now I am getting more that 2. I am also open to any other solution

Comment: The first RegEx pattern looks good to me, the first match is the full match and the next 2 are the grouped matches. Just always skip the first one when you read in the matches in your code.

Comment: Can you add an example of your desired output? Because near as I can figure, the first code block is working in the manner you are describing.

Comment: The first element of a match (`splitted[0]`) always returns the entire string that matches. Just look for `splitted[1]` and `splitted[2]`. Based on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec): *The returned array has the matched text as the first item, and then one item for each capturing parenthesis that matched containing the text that was captured.*

Comment: Your text example is "CSE101" and your code example is `CSE1011`, You should edit this for clarity, if it is an unintended conflict.

Comment: Thank you Terry for pointing the link. I was looking for that.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be so accurate you can also try with use of second paramater *limit* of [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Try [`var res = courscrCode.split(/\s*(\d+)/, 2);`](https://jsfiddle.net/xt09jy8m/)

Comment: its for a web app restful post..so i need to do the validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `splitted` array in **SECOND** sample code is:

```
 ["", "CSE", "1011", ""]
```

- If your input text `courscrCode` is always one course code, you should find prefix in [1] and number in [2]
- If input text may be more than just course code to validate, some changes are required.

Note: first empty item in array is all characters before `CSE` and last item in array is all characters after `1011`. **It's not whole matched value**

```js
     var courscrCode = 'CSE1011';
     var courseRegex = /([A-Z]{2,})(?:\s*)([0-9]{3,})?$/g;
     var prefix = '' ;
     var suffix = '' ;     
     if (courscrCode.match(courseRegex)) {
       var splitted = courscrCode.split(courseRegex);
       console.log(splitted.length);
       if (splitted.length > 1) {
         prefix = splitted[1]; 
         suffix = splitted[2];
         //or:
         splitted.splice(0,1);
         splitted.splice(2,1);
         console.log(splitted);
       }
     } else {
       console.log('course code mangled');
     }
```

Comment: *It is the whole value* as per the documentation cited above **and all code snippets on this page**, and that's what the OP is seeing. The only way you get empty elements is if you have empty capture groups `()`, empty alternation `(a|)` that was chosen by the engine, or evaluations that can return empty values `(a)(\s*)(b)` against `"ab"` would return `["ab","a","","b"]`. `(a)(\s|)(b)` would return the same. Also nested captures that were never reached like `(a)(\s()|)(b)`. It's complex.

Comment: topic: "Need to **split** University Course code into prefix and suffix using regex" and second code uses `split` function and I'm writing about `split` function! @cfqueryparam

Comment: This one is also working. Could not accept two answers and accepting the first one as less looping involved. Also my personal choice

Answer (score 2):

As Terry noted above, MDN states that the array returned by regex will **always** include the matched text as the first item. The code below will remove the first element.

```js
var courscrCode = 'CSE1011';
var courseRegex = /([A-Z]{2,})(?:\s*)([0-9]{3,})?$/g;
var splitted = courseRegex.exec(courscrCode);
splitted.splice(0,1);
console.log(splitted);
```

Comment: This one is working. thanks for pointing the correct MDN docs. Accepting this answer

Comment: "Accepting this answer" @RezwanKhan